# Error in installing LanguageTool-1.5 on LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, language-support

I am getting the following error while installing the latest LanguageTool-1.5 on LibreOffice. 
I have already uninstalled the previous languagetool using the below command. Please help me to install the latest LanguageTool.

`$ unopkg remove org.openoffice.languagetool.oxt`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the openoffice.org-java-common package. Just search for it in the software center

This seems to be a longstanding error in Ubuntu.

Comment: For libreoffice, this package is now called libreoffice-java-common